# Subtyping without inheritance and inheritance without subtyping?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, subtyping

My instructor posted a sample midterm for us to do and I am confused on the following question:

Show an example of inheritance without subtyping and subtyping without inheritance.

We are using the following definitions, and we are programming in Java: http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/pl2006/lecturenotes/lecture-notes/node28.html

What would be a good way to represent these two ideas?

Comment: Can you remove the link and summarize it's contents as part of your question? A lot of us cannot/will not follow links to random sites because we're in work, also it lowers the quality of your question because once the site/document is removed your question ceases to make sense. Once this is done I'll remove my downvote and vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

As per the listed definition of sub-typing:

> Subtyping refers to compatibility of interfaces. A type B is a subtype of A if every function that can be invoked on an object of type A can also be invoked on an object of type B.

Sub-typing in Java is basically akin to extending or implementing an interface in Java. For example:

```
interface Fish {
    void swim();
}

interface FlyingFish extends Fish {
    void fly();
}
```

Here, `FlyingFish` is a sub-type of `Fish` because a flying fish is always a type of fish.

As per the listed definition of inheritance:

> Inheritance refers to reuse of implementations. A type B inherits from another type A if some functions for B are written in terms of functions of A.

This definition inheritance refers to implementation inheritance in Java. This is usually also a form of sub-typing, but not always with poorly designed taxonomies that you will see as you progress in your career. ;-) For example:

```
class FlyingFish {
    void swim() {
        // implementation code to swim in water
    }

    void fly() {
        // implementation code to jump out of the water and fly
    }
}

class Bird extends FlyingFish {
    // no need to implement fly, reuse implementation of flying fish

    void swim() {
        // do nothing implementation - most birds can't swim.
    }
}

class Fish extends FlyingFish {
    void fly() {
        // do nothing implementation - most fish can't fly.
    }

    // no need to implement swim, reuse implementation of flying fish
}
```

Here, both `Bird` and `Fish` inappropriately inherit from `FlyingFish`, even though neither `Bird` nor `Fish` are sub-types of a flying fish.

Hope that helps, comment if you have any follow up questions. Also, a book that might be worth your while is *Effective Java 2nd Ed.* by Josh Boch. In this book, Bloch gives some really great content on these topics.

Comment: I've downvoted this because I can see no definition of the problem in the question or your answer. If you can fix this I'll happily remove my downvote. Typically on SO we don't like questions or answers that link to other sites without offering a summary of the content for those of us who can't follow the links while we're at work. Ty.

Comment: A bit picky for my tastes by I'll bite. See revised answer.

Comment: Ty -- I actually couldn't understand the answer (or question actually) without the inline definitions. I'm in work and the linked site it blocked to me, so it may be picky, but for a lot of us its vital.